# Remove Browser Autofill feature

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I need to remove the browser's autofill/suggestion feature.

[image: Material UI Autofill]

This autofill is disabled using autocomplete="off" in Textfield component. once I do that this brings browser's auto fill feature

[image: Browser Autofill]

In Edge, If I turn off the "Save and fill the personal info" option in "Settings/Profile/Personal info" the above suggestion is not shown. Is there any way without turning off that setting I can remove the autofill feature using Material UI TextField property or CSS property "input:-webkit-autofill"

Answer (score 0):

If `autocomplete` fails to work, most likely it's a bug or for some reason, react is preventing the attribute from being modified.

However, I know a simple way to bypass by changing the `type` attribute to something random, where the browser can't understand what it should ask from the user and therefore, the browser can't prompt an autofill.

For example on a standard HTML input tag:

```
<input type="inputText"/>
```

This will still treat it as an input field, however, it will not attempt to autofill.

Comment: I am using material UI component and I tried using type="inputText" it doesn't work. The problem is not with component  I am able to disable the component's autofill. I need to disable the browser's autofill. That should be handled at CSS level with input:-webkit-autofill

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely a bug, the solution I've found works best is to have auto-complete have a hard coded random value which will prevent a user from using auto-complete...

Try this:

```
<input type='password' name='pass' autocomplete='password' />
```

In terms of the auto-complete value you can have anything you want there.

New edit:

```
<script>

    // Execute this code when page is
    // totally loaded
    $(document).ready(function () {
      
        /* Setting the autocomplete of 
           input field to off to make 
           autofill to disable */
        $("#name").prop("autocomplete", "off");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is not with component I am able to disable the component's autofill. I need to disable the browser's autofill.

Comment: Ohhh I see, unfortunately I don't know of anyway to disable the browsers autofill, but you can use jQuery to disable inputs with a common class name or id...

Answer (score 0):

Its browser functionality which you cant handle from code level. If you want to prevent it than you have to made setting changes in browser

Turning Off Autofill in Chrome

Click the Chrome menu icon. (Three dots at top right of screen.)
Click on Settings.
In the "Autofill" section, expand the area for which you wish to disable Autofill.
Toggle the setting OFF if it is on.  The system will automatically save your settings.

More details found here => https://support.iclasspro.com/hc/en-us/articles/218569268-How-Do-I-Disable-or-Clear-AutoFill-AutoComplete-Information-

Comment: Is there any way we could handle that using "input:-webkit-autofill" CSS property?

Comment: you can try below

/* Change autocomplete styles in WebKit */
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  border: 1px solid green;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: green;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #000 inset;
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}

Comment: by use of the above code we can change the format of autofill but not remove it though.

Answer (score 0):

So for html you can simply put autocomplete="new-password" in your
Auto-complete="off" can also be used nut it has some drawbacks.

Banks and other security institutes turn auto complete off .Problem    is user change frequently their passwords and fields and  use simple passwords to remeber.So auto complete is good feature in these cases.

But you can try this solution if you want .I hope it will work fine

```
 <input type="password" autocomplete="new-password">
```

Comment: The problem is not with component I am able to disable the component's autofill. I need to disable the browser's autofill.

Answer (score 0):

you can add `autocomplete="off"` to your `form` or `input` but many modern browsers do not support autocomplete="off" for login fields

but you can prevent it using `autocomplete="new-password"`

> Preventing autofilling with autocomplete="new-password"

for more information check this link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#the_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields